# Problem getting date from input type=date(freemarker) with spring boot

Tags: html, spring-boot, freemarker

I have got a table letter. When I update record, I don't see on the view date of record.

I tried to get date as follows:

`<input type="date" name="dateSend" value="${letter.dateSend}">`

I debugged my code, in the controller I get the date, but in the view, I don't see it. 
When I changed type from type date to text, I see the date send of the letter, but I want use type of date.

## My code:

### Service:

```
public Iterable<Letters> updateLetter(
String numberList, String titleLetter, String addressee,
Date dateSend, Letters letter
){
letter.setNumberList(numberList);
letter.setTitleLetter(titleLetter);
letter.setAddressee(addressee);
letter.setDateSend(dateSend);

letterRepository.save(letter);

return getAllLetters();
}

public Iterable<Letters> updateLetter(
String numberList, String titleLetter, String addressee,
Date dateSend, Letters letter
){
letter.setNumberList(numberList);
letter.setTitleLetter(titleLetter);
letter.setAddressee(addressee);
letter.setDateSend(dateSend);

letterRepository.save(letter);

return getAllLetters();
}
```

### Controller:

```
@PostMapping("editLetter")
public String editLetter(
@RequestParam String numberList, String titleLetter,
String addressee, @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date dateSend,
Model model, @RequestParam("letterId") Letters letter
){
letterService.updateLetter(numberList, titleLetter, addressee, dateSend, 
letter);
model.addAttribute("letter", letter);

return "redirect:/letter";
}
@GetMapping("/del/{letter}")
public String deleteLetters(
@PathVariable Letters letter
){
letterService.deleteLetter(letter);

return "redirect:/letter";
}
```

### View:

```
<#import "parts/common.ftl" as c>
<@c.page>
Letter editor
<form action="editLetter" method="post">
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Number list: </label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="numberList" value="${letter.numberList}">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Title letter: </label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="titleLetter" value="${letter.titleLetter}">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Addressee: </label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="addressee" value="${letter.addressee}">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Date send: </label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="date" name="dateSend" class="form-control" value="${letter.getDateSend()}" placeholder="Please enter date of sending">
</div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" value="${letter.id}" name="letterId">
<input type="hidden" value="${_csrf.token}" name="_csrf">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

I expected: date od my record, but my result is dd.mm.rrrr

Please help me! :)

Comment: What exactly does `${letter.getDateSend()}` print again? I guess it's not literally `dd.mm.rrrr`. (By the way, `${letter.dateSend}` is nicer, but of course has the same output.)

Comment: Thank's for your answer. At first I used `${letter.dateSend}`, but it's doesn't matter.
I don't see field value, prints exactly `dd.mm.rrrr`. In the controller I have filed value, but in the view when I used type date `<input type="date" name="dateSend" class="form-control" value="${letter.dateSend}">`, I don't see this value and when I change type on text I see my value (`<input type="text" name="dateSend" class="form-control" value="${letter.dateSend}">`

Comment: Ah, of course... See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you see `dd.mm.rrrr` as is in the output, that means that FreeMarker was miss-configured to format dates as `dd.mm.rrrr` *literally*. Someone tried to set the `date_format` configuration setting to `dd.mm.rrrr`, but actually set it to `'dd.mm.rrrr'`, which includes the `'`-s. Remove those `'`-s. After that you will also realize that the correct pattern would be `dd.MM.yyyy`.

Comment: I understand what do you write, but I don't understand, how to fix this problem. Could you tell me what am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: In the template nothing is wrong. Find where FreeMarker is configured. Or, just search for `dd.mm.rrrr` in the project. Maybe it's in a `.properties` file somewhere.